# Ejecutar el evento Click con controles dinámicos en Windows form c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

les explico estoy generando x botones de manera dinámica, pero no logro hacer que cada botón generado tenga su evento Click con una acción diferente en cada uno, normalmente lo estaba haciendo de la siguiente manera

```
Button mybutton = new Button(){
     //Declaración de propiedades
};
mybutton.Click += MyButton_Click;
```

El problema de el código anterior es que todos los botones hacen la misma acción hay alguna manera de que cada uno tenga su propio evento Click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por cada botón que creas dinámicamente debes tener un método listo para asignárselo:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Código
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Código
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Código
}

Button myButton1 = new Button();
Button myButton2 = new Button();
Button myButton3 = new Button();

myButton1.Click += button1_Click;
myButton2.Click += button2_Click;
myButton3.Click += button3_Click;
```

Aquí tienes tres métodos para asignárselo a cada botón que crees dinámicamente. Debes tener en cuenta que los métodos que enlaces al **evento Click** deben tener determinada estructura que debes respetar, es decir, el método debe ser declarado como **void** y recibir dos parámetros, uno de tipo **object** y otro de tipo **EventArgs**.

También puedes emplear **métodos anónimos**, de esta forma no tienes que declarar métodos independientes como te dije más arriba:

```
button1.Click += (o, ev) =>
{
   int a = 10;
   int b = 20;
   int suma = a + b;

   MessageBox.Show(suma.ToString());
};
```

Aquí por ejemplo enlazas al **evento click** del botón con un **método anónimo** que suma dos números y muestra el resultado de la suma en un mensaje.